# Initialize tuple member in constructor of variadic template class

Tags: c++, templates, stdtuple

Suppose I have a class of a variable:

```
class Variable
{
  const std::string name;
  const double scale;

public:
  Variable(const std::string& _name, double _scale) : name(_name), scale(_scale) { }
};
```

Now I define a class of a system containing variables:

```
template<class... T>
class System
{
 std::tuple<T...> variables;

public:
 System(???) : ??? { }
};
```

How can I define the constructor of the `System` that will somehow pass its agruments to `variables` to initialize each of them? I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
class VAR1 : public Variable { };
class VAR2 : public Variable { };

System<VAR1, VAR2> s{ /* init values: ("VAR1", 10), ("VAR2", 20) */};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have the correct constructors in the derived class:

```
template<class... T>
class System
{
    std::tuple<T...> variables;
public:
    System(const T&... t) : variables(t...) { }
};

System<VAR1, VAR2> s({"VAR1", 10}, {"VAR2", 20});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I see that I should reconsider the initial idea because I don't want to define (identical) constructors in each derived class: I wanted to use derived classes as mere tags to discern different variables by types (playing roles of names) instead of numbers in `std::get<...>`.

Comment: @Evgeny Putting `using Variable::Variable;` in the derived classes allows it to be initialized this way too.

Comment: This code is not compiling you need to change variables(t...)

Comment: @Kapil Nice spot, thank you! Can't believe I forgot something so obvious.